# Arduino AC low voltage to GPIO

Tags: arduino, ac, gpio

Very new to this so please forgive any noob type statements

I have an AC plug in door bell, it produces a low voltage AC signal to a speaker.

I want to plum this into a Arduino GPIO so I know when the door bell is pressed

Am I safe just to hook this up or will this burn my home down?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what "an AC plug in door bell" is. Can you link to a datasheet, add a photo, measure the AC speaker signal you are trying to tap into ...

Comment: If you have a doorbell step-down transformer, you likely won't hurt your house. Your Arduino may fare worse, though.

Comment: Is it a wireless unit like this: https://www.walmart.com/ip/Honeywell-Plug-in-Wireless-Door-Chime-and-Push-Button/13952364

Comment: Yes jonk it is, although I am over the pond in the UK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not safe. You must limit the input to your arduino to 0..5V DC.

In your shoes I would probably use a suitable (AC!) optocoupler like a PC814. Connect the LEDs of the PC814 to your AC source with a suitable resistor (1k, for a start), in paralel with the bell. The PC814 output transistor can be connected to your Arduino input, maybe with a pullup resistor (again, try 1k).

Comment: Thanks very much for all the advice and help. Learning the long way round is taxing for everyone else! I'll get my self one and give it a go. I just wanted to understand fully that Ac to dc even at a low voltage was a problem!